# react actions on child leads to re-render of parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

I stopped on quite a simple code

```js
function App() {
  let [items, setItems] = useState(getSessionStorage())

  console.log(items);
  if (items) {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {items.map((item) => FormLine(item))}
      </div>

    );
  }
  else { return (null) }
}

export default App;
```

The App component takes external function getSessionStorage which returns sessionStorage certain content or item if called for a first time.

FormLine is a function that renders form fields

```js
const { name, netPrice, quantity, vat, grossPrice } = props;
let [inputName, setInputName] = useState(name);

return (
  <input_.outerWrapper id='my_form' className="my_form" >
    <input
      required
      minLength="1"
      maxLength="20"
      pattern="[a-zA-ZąĄććęęłŁńŃóÓśŚżŻŹŹ ]+"
      placeholder="Nazwa..."
      type="text"
      ref={input}
      value={inputName}
      onChange={(e) => setInputName((inputName = e.target.value))}
    />
  </input_.outerWrapper>
)
```

and so on with this pattern. The problem is that when I do type letters in FormLine, App component re-renders with every keystroke. That is very ugly and possibly leads to errors, and that is something I have not expected and do not understand. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Thank you, I am new to hooks. That is other story then in class components and so there is my surprise. Can one prevent it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't think child re rendering will result in parent re rendering as well otherwise there's no point in creating child components if they will render the parent as well.

Comment: @CertainPerformance So if `console.log("sample")` anything in parent component then whenever the child state changes, it will log "sample" ?

Comment: Yes, I just used it firstly to check whether it receives correct values, then saw that it rerenders. Yest, console.log()is the marker in this case

Comment: You need to use key prop inside the list
      {items.map((item, index)=><div key={index}>FormLine(item))</div>}

Comment: sure with key, that is to keep things as simple as possible, there are also some other fragments I do not put

Comment: @CertainPerformance Can you share some sample code where parent is re rendered because in my case parent is not re rendered when child is? Also to re render a parent we pass setState method to child only to change the state of parent and cause re rendering of parent, right?

Comment: @maya_nk99 Oops, I got myself confused, you're completely right, it's the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think child component re-rendering will cause parent re-rendering. It's not true.
The reason you got this weird behavior because in your code you are not using FormLine as a component but as a normal function
so instead of this:

```
return (
      <div className="App">
        {items.map((item) => FormLine(item))}
      </div>

    );
```

use this:

```
return (
      <div className="App">
        {items.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <FormLine name={item} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
```

You can check the demo in this CodeSandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-leaf-zvn2g